# Foreground service doesn't start activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I want to start an activity even if the app is killed. Below API 29 there is no problem but above 29 even though service is triggered in background startActivity isn't working.

Here is my service class

```
class MyService : Service() {

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("setContentTitle")
        .setContentText("setContentText")
        .build()


    val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MyActivity::class.java)
    mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    startActivity(mIntent)

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder)

    return START_NOT_STICKY

}



companion object {
    const val CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id"
    const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 5
    const val CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_name"
}
```

}

in Manifest I added FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service android:name=".service.MyService" />
<receiver android:name=".receiver.MyReceiver" />
```

and here is my receiver class, above API 29 I want to start a service

```
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    intent?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            context?.startForegroundService(Intent(context, MyService::class.java))
        } else {
            val intentActivity = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
            intentActivity.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context?.startActivity(intentActivity)
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: So, `onReceive()` get triggered and the foreground service is launched?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PendingIntent here.

- PendingIntent is an intent that will perform at a later time or in other words PendingIntent specifies an action to take in future. The main differences between a pendingIntent and regular intent is pendingIntent will perform at a later time where Normal/Regular intent starts immediately.

It comes with different use cases like this.

- PendingIntent.getActivity() — This will start an Activity like calling context.startActivity()
- PendingIntent.getBroadcast() — This will perform a Broadcast like calling context.sendBroadcast()
- PendingIntent.getService() — This will start a Services like calling context.startService()
- PendingIntent.getForegroundService() — This will start a foregroundService like calling context.startForegroundService()

There are tons of examples you'll find on the internet about it. Just google it & it'll get you work done. :)

Comment: But I don't want it to start at a later time, it should start immediately.